# Multiple Gridviews on the same page, with multiple GridViewCommandEventArgs, buttonfield gets the index/id from the wrong Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview

So I have these two Gridviews. The first one named 'GridView1' works normally, but the second one named 'Gridview2', when I click on the ButtonField to get the ID from inside the GridView ID column cell , it gets the correct row index, but from the wrong GridView, it gets it from 'GridView1' instead of 'GridView2' where the code for the functionality ButtonField is inside the GridViewCommandEventArgs _RowCommand code block. I for the life of me can't figure out why it's getting it from the first one, even the e.CommandSource(.ID.toString()) say's it's from  GridView2, but the Column ID i get is picked up from the first. The two GridViews are identical, except the second one has more ButtonFields and is a custom view of the first one, with only selected IDs being displayed on the second GridView(GridView2). This is kind of my first post, your help is greatly appreciated. Tried searching google, but my issue seems so specific, it's kind of hard to make it broader to find online.

C# Code: Some Global Variabes if it helps:

```
public partial class userArea : System.Web.UI.Page {

static string getCustomView;
static string hash;
static string authNum;
static string addToMyCustomView;
static string getDistinctArray;
static string getFirstName;
static string getLastName;
static string getUsernameToAddToComp;
static string getNotes;
static string getUserSessionStatus;
```

ASPX Code: Gridview1

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" PageSize="7" 
            Width="1344px" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="lheID" HeaderText="ID" 
                    SortExpression="lheID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lhewirelessGiant" HeaderText="Wireless Giant" 
                    SortExpression="lhewirelessGiant" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lheFName" HeaderText="First Name" 
                    SortExpression="lheFName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lheInitials" HeaderText="Initials" 
                    SortExpression="lheInitials" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lheLName" HeaderText="Last Name" 
                    SortExpression="lheLName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lhePrimaryEmail" HeaderText="Primary Email" 
                    SortExpression="lhePrimaryEmail" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lheDisplayName" HeaderText="Display Name" 
                    SortExpression="lheDisplayName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lheNameID" HeaderText="Name ID" 
                    SortExpression="lheNameID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="lheWhosLookingAtThis" HeaderText="Who's looking @ this?" 
                    SortExpression="lheNameID" />
                    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="images/copy.png" CommandName="CopyToMe"
            HeaderText="Add to My List" Text="Add to My List" />

            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

ASPX Code: GridView2

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" PageSize="7" 
            Width="1344px" onrowcommand="GridView2_RowCommand">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="lheID" HeaderText="ID" 
                    SortExpression="lheID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lhewirelessGiant" HeaderText="Wireless Giant" 
                    SortExpression="lhewirelessGiant" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lheFName" HeaderText="First Name" 
                    SortExpression="lheFName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lheInitials" HeaderText="Initials" 
                    SortExpression="lheInitials" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lheLName" HeaderText="Last Name" 
                    SortExpression="lheLName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lhePrimaryEmail" HeaderText="Primary Email" 
                    SortExpression="lhePrimaryEmail" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lheDisplayName" HeaderText="Display Name" 
                    SortExpression="lheDisplayName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="lheNameID" HeaderText="Name ID" 
                    SortExpression="lheNameID" />


            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="images/Apply.png" CommandName="Complete"
            HeaderText="Complete" Text="Add to My List" />
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="images/Display.png" CommandName="AddComputer"
            HeaderText="Comp.(+)" Text="Add to My List" />

            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="images/Text.png" CommandName="AddNotes"
            HeaderText="View/Add Notes" Text="Add to My List" />
             <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="images/Info.png" CommandName="Info"
            HeaderText="More Info" Text="Add to My List" />

            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

C# Code: GridView1_RowCommand

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string key = e.CommandName;

    if (key == "CopyToMe")
    {

        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView2.DataBind();


        int index = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        GridView grid = (GridView)e.CommandSource;
        GridViewRow row = grid.Rows[index];
        TableCell tblCell = row.Cells[0];
        authNum = tblCell.Text;


        //update the who is
        try
        {

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["legalHoldConnString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE lhentries SET lheWhosLookingAtThis = '" + getFirstName + " " + getLastName + "' WHERE lheID = '" + authNum + "'  ;");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader1.Close();



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }

        addToMyCustomView = null;

        //get the custum view from my row

        try
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["legalHoldConnString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT lhuCustomeView FROM lhusers WHERE lhUUsername = '" + getUsername.Text + "' AND lhupassword = '" + hash + "';");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            addToMyCustomView = ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close(); con.Dispose();

            // Response.Write(getCustomView);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }
       // Response.Write(addToMyCustomView);
        //perform adding string operation

        if (addToMyCustomView == null)
        {
            addToMyCustomView = authNum;
        }
        else 
        {
            addToMyCustomView = addToMyCustomView + "," + authNum;
        }


        //update the users custome view
        try
        {

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["legalHoldConnString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE lhusers SET lhuCustomeView = '" + addToMyCustomView + "' WHERE lhupassword='" + hash.ToString() + "' AND lhuUsername = '" + Session["userSessionU"].ToString() + "'  ;");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader1.Close();



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }

        //Response.Redirect("userArea.aspx");
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView2.DataBind();


        //get rid of duplicates in the array and then update

        //make char array to be used as split delimitter for the string
        char[] splitOn = { ',' };
        //split the string into a array
        string[] idElements = addToMyCustomView.Split(splitOn);
        //only takes var but, makes the array unique, with no duplicates making it distinct
        var temp = idElements.Distinct().ToArray();
        //convert the array back into a string delimitted by a comma
        string getDistinctArray = String.Join(",", temp);

        //FOR TESTING WHAT GETS PULLED FROM THE USERS CUSTOM VIEW
        //Response.Write(getDistinctArray.ToString() + "this is the one");
        Response.Write(authNum);
        //update with distinct array
        try
        {

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["legalHoldConnString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE lhusers SET lhuCustomeView = '" + getDistinctArray + "' WHERE lhupassword='" + hash.ToString() + "' AND lhuUsername = '" + Session["userSessionU"].ToString() + "'  ;");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader1.Close();



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }

        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView2.DataBind();

        Response.Write(grid.ID.ToString() + " - " + authNum + " - " + index);

    }

    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView2.DataBind();

}
```

C# Code: GridView2_RowCommand

```
 protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string key = e.CommandName;
    //Add computer
    if (key == "AddComputer")
    {
        //Visuals
        temp.Visible = true;
        temp.Style.Add("width", "100%");
        temp.Style.Add("height", "100%");
        temp.Style.Add("top", "0px");
        temp.Style.Add("left", "0px");

        topPanel.Style.Add("width", "300px");
        topPanel.Style.Add("height", "220px");
        //topPanel.Style.Add("margin", "0px auto");
        //topPanel.Style.Add("margin", "0px auto");
        Button2.Visible = true;
        addAComputer.Visible = true;
        computerTable.Visible = true;
        temp.Visible = true;
        topPanel.Visible = true;

        //Functionality

        //////UNRESOLVED: THERE ARE TWO GRIDVIEWS. THE FIRST ONE NAME GRIDVIEW1 WORKS WITHOUT A HITCH, THE SECOND GRIDVIEW NAMES GRIDVIEW2, WHEN THE BUTTONFIELD IS CLICKED THE ROW FOR THE PHYSICAL GRIDVIEW ITSELF, THE INDEX IS OBTAINED CORRECTLY, FOR THE COMMANDSOURCE, WHEN CONVERTING THE ID OF THE COMMANDSOURCE SO AS TO SEE WHICH OF THE GRIDVIEWS THE COMMANDSOURCE IS COMING FROM, THE COMMANDSOURCE SAYS GRIDVIEW2 WHICH IS CORRECT. WHEN THE INDEX OF THE COMMAND ARGUMENT IS USED TO GET THE GRIDVIEWROW, IT DOES GET THE CORRECT ROW, BUT IT'S STILL POINTING TO THE WRONG GRIDVIEW WHICH IS GRIDVIEW1 WHEN IT SHOULD BE GRIDVIEW2

        int index = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString()); // gets the right index(row from the gridview itself)
        GridView grid2 = (GridView)e.CommandSource; // saying it gets the right gridview        
        GridViewRow row = grid2.Rows[index]; //correct row, wrong gridview


        TableCell tblCell = row.Cells[0];
        authNum = tblCell.Text;

        //TEST
       //int authNums = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.)].Value);

        TableCell place7 = row.Cells[7];
        getUsernameToAddToComp = place7.Text;

        //Response.Write(getUsernameToAddToComp);
        Response.Write(grid2.ID.ToString() + " - " + authNum + " - " + index);
    }

    if (key == "AddNotes")
    {
        //Visuals

        temp.Visible = true;
        temp.Style.Add("width", "100%");
        temp.Style.Add("height", "100%");
        temp.Style.Add("top", "0px");
        temp.Style.Add("left", "0px");

        topPanel.Style.Add("width", "300px");
        topPanel.Style.Add("height", "220px");
        //topPanel.Style.Add("margin", "0px auto");
        //topPanel.Style.Add("margin", "0px auto");
        addNotesDiv.Visible = true;
        notesTable.Visible = true;
        notesTable.Style.Add("z-index", "9");
        //Functionality

        int index = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        GridView grid = (GridView)e.CommandSource;
        GridViewRow row = grid.Rows[index];
        TableCell tblCell = row.Cells[0];
        authNum = tblCell.Text;

        //get notes from entries table using authnum if any
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["legalHoldConnString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT lheNotes FROM lhentries WHERE lheID = '" + authNum + "' ;");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            getNotes = ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close(); con.Dispose();

            // Response.Write(getCustomView);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }
        //insert notes from db into text box

        noteTextBox.Text = getNotes;
        getNotes = "";

        //TableCell place7 = row.Cells[7];
        //getNotes = place7.Text;

        //Response.Write(getUsernameToAddToComp);

    }

    if (key == "Info")
    {
        int index = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        GridView grid = (GridView)e.CommandSource;
        GridViewRow row = grid.Rows[index];
        TableCell tblCell = row.Cells[0];
        authNum = tblCell.Text;

        Session["getIDForMoreInfo"] = authNum;

        Response.Redirect("allUserInfo.aspx");
    }

    if (key == "Complete")
    {
        //Response.Write("");
        GridView2.DataBind();

        int index = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        GridView grid = (GridView)e.CommandSource;
        GridViewRow row = grid.Rows[index];
        TableCell tblCell = row.Cells[0];
        authNum = tblCell.Text;

        //update the the entry to the status of completed
        try
        {

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["legalHoldConnString"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE lhentries SET lheCompleted = 'True' WHERE lheID = '" + authNum + "'; ");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            MySqlDataReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader1.Close();

            //this is a test to see if the button is picking up the correct row number
           // Response.Write(authNum);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());

        }

        //GridView2.DataSource = "SqlDataSource2";
        GridView2.DataBind();
       // Response.Redirect("userArea.aspx");
        authNum = null;

    }


}
```

It's probably something so simple, and I'm just over thinking. Thanks if you can help.

Comment: try to specify which gridview you are using as you use - GridView grid = (GridView)e.CommandSource; - for both gridviews. try to set variable names to the specific gridview. GridView1 = (GridView)e.CommandSource;

Comment: just tried that, but still no go. GridView2 still pulls the ID from GridView1

Comment: Do you really need to get the Gridview from e.CommandSource? Why not just use GridView2? you know the Grid you need so I don't see the point of getting the gridview from e.CommandSource.

Comment: That's actually a good idea, i'll try that and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: nope, still no luck;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, the issue that i figured out by chance was because of something in my page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Session
    if (Session["userSessionU"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("LHLogin.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        getUsername.Text = Session["userSessionU"].ToString();
    }
   getUserSessionStatus =  Session["userAccountType"].ToString();
    //if super admin, show super admin controls
   if (getUserSessionStatus == "Super-Admin")
   {
       adminOptions.Visible = true;
   }
   else
   {
       adminOptions.Visible = false;
   }

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView2.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
        GridView1.DataBind();
        GridView2.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource2";
        GridView2.DataBind();


    }

    //display for divs
   // topPanel.Visible = false;
    temp.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("opacity", "0.6");
    //computerTable.Visible = false;

    //refresh gridviews

    SqlDataSource2.DataBind();
    GridView2.DataBind();

    //hash password session string
    hash = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(Session["userSessionPW"].ToString() + "", "SHA1");

    //get the users last name

    try
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["legalHoldConnString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT lhulname FROM lhusers WHERE lhUUsername = '" + getUsername.Text + "' AND lhupassword = '" + hash + "';");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        getLastName = ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close(); con.Dispose();

        // Response.Write(getCustomView);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {


    }

    //get the users first name

    try
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["legalHoldConnString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT lhufname FROM lhusers WHERE lhUUsername = '" + getUsername.Text + "' AND lhupassword = '" + hash + "';");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        getFirstName = ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close(); con.Dispose();

        // Response.Write(getCustomView);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {


    }

    try
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["legalHoldConnString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT lhuCustomeView FROM lhusers WHERE lhUUsername = '" + getUsername.Text + "' AND lhupassword = '"+ hash +"';");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        getCustomView = ((string)cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        con.Close(); con.Dispose();

       // Response.Write(getCustomView);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {


    }




    //clear the customview string


    //adv search options for entries
    //------   ----------------------


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    searchBtn.Focus();
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE (lheNameID LIKE '%" + searchEntryTable.Text.ToString() + "%' ) ORDER BY lheID DESC";
    if (firstNameRB.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE (lheFName LIKE '%" + searchEntryTable.Text.ToString() + "%' ) ORDER BY lheID DESC";
    }
    else if (lastNameRB.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE (lheLName LIKE '%" + searchEntryTable.Text.ToString() + "%' ) ORDER BY lheID DESC";
    }
    else if (emailRB.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE (lhePrimaryEmail LIKE '%" + searchEntryTable.Text.ToString() + "%' ) ORDER BY lheID DESC";
    }
    else if (displayNameRB.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE (lheDisplayName LIKE '%" + searchEntryTable.Text.ToString() + "%' ) ORDER BY lheID DESC";
    }
    else if (nameID.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE (lheNameID LIKE '%" + searchEntryTable.Text.ToString() + "%' ) ORDER BY lheID DESC";
    }
    else if (whosLookingAtThis.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE (lheWhosLookingAtthis LIKE '%" + searchEntryTable.Text.ToString() + "%' ) ORDER BY lheID DESC";
    }
    else if (wirelessGiantRB.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE (lhewirelessGiant LIKE '%" + searchEntryTable.Text.ToString() + "%' ) ORDER BY lheID DESC";
    }
    else 
    {
        nameID.Checked = true;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //for my table entries
    if (Session["getSearchForMyTable"] != null)
   {

       SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE  lheID IN (" + getCustomView + ") AND (lheNameID LIKE '%" + searchMyTable.Text.ToString() + "%' ) AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC;";

    if (firstNameRB.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE  lheID IN (" + getCustomView + ") AND (lheFName LIKE '%" + searchMyTable.Text.ToString() + "%' ) AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC;";

    }
    else if (lastNameRB.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE  lheID IN (" + getCustomView + ") AND (lheLName LIKE '%" + searchMyTable.Text.ToString() + "%' )  AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC;";

    }
    else if (emailRB.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE  lheID IN (" + getCustomView + ") AND (lhePrimaryEmail LIKE '%" + searchMyTable.Text.ToString() + "%' )  AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC;";

    }
    else if (displayNameRB.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE  lheID IN (" + getCustomView + ") AND (lheDisplayName LIKE '%" + searchMyTable.Text.ToString() + "%' )  AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC;";

    }
    else if (nameID.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE  lheID IN (" + getCustomView + ") AND (lheNameID LIKE '%" + searchMyTable.Text.ToString() + "%' )  AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC;";


        // Response.Write("this test works if u can se ethis");
    }
    else if (whosLookingAtThis.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE  lheID IN (" + getCustomView + ") AND (lheWhosLookingAtthis LIKE '%" + searchMyTable.Text.ToString() + "%' ) AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC;";

    }
    else if (wirelessGiantRB.Checked)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries  WHERE  lheID IN (" + getCustomView + ") AND (lhewirelessGiant LIKE '%" + searchMyTable.Text.ToString() + "%' )  AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC;";


    }
   }


    if ((getCustomView == null) )
    {
        //Perform the custom view with the select command
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries WHERE lheID  = 0  AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC; ";
    }
    else
    {

        try
        {

            //Perform the custom view with the select command
            SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries WHERE lheID IN (" + getCustomView + ")  AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC; ";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }


    getCustomView = null;
}
```

But The main issue was in this block of code here:

```
if ((getCustomView == null) )
    {
        //Perform the custom view with the select command
        SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries WHERE lheID  = 0  AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC; ";
    }
    else
    {

        try
        {

            //Perform the custom view with the select command
            SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT lheID, lhewirelessGiant, lheFName, lheInitials, lheLName, lhePrimaryEmail, lheDisplayName, lheNameID, lheWhosLookingAtthis FROM lhentries WHERE lheID IN (" + getCustomView + ")  AND lheCompleted = 'False' ORDER BY lheID DESC; ";
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
```

So now I have to figure out a better select statement so that when the custom view becomes null it doesn't default to the first data source, giving the appearance that it was taking the same id's from a different data source. Might have to use some inline scripting, i'm still taking opinions but this should probably close this question.

Comment: Duh, kind of forgot to say what the issue was. The issue was in the latter of the if statement, in the else block. Seems like the 'getCustomView' wouldn't hold after the page loaded, i know i made it null at the end, so when i went to click on the button  in the gridview, and the page did a post back, the 'sqldatasource2' would kind of be exactly the same as 'sqldatasource1' giving the appearance that the I thought i was selecting from the first gridview. This is all theory, so in theory again, i think all i'd have to do is add (!IsPostback) around the if statement.